# Haskell: anonymous function with two arguments

Tags: haskell, anonymous-function

I have the following anonymous function:

```
(\x y -> y+y) (5*(7+20))
```

As far as I understand anonymous functions, x should be (5*(7+20)) and y is not given (which is where it gets fishy). When I try to execute that function, GHCI tells me the return value is

```
Integer -> Integer
```

So obviously my interpretation is wrong here and I just can't see why. Can anyone explain to me what is happening here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at it this way: if you had provided a value for y, you'd get an integer.  If you don't provide a value, you'll get an expression which takes an integer (which you call y) and returns an integer, i.e. a function

```
Integer -> Integer
```

This works for named functions too.  E.g.

```
plus :: Int -> Int -> Int
plus x y = x + y
```

You can check in ghci that the type of `plus 1` is `Int -> Int`.  In fact, this process works for any function in Haskell.  You read more at the [HaskellWiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_application).

Answer (score 15):

Note that

```
\x y -> y+y
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
\x -> (\y -> y+y)
```

i.e. rather than saying “a lambda function of two arguments” you might say it's a function of only one argument. The return type just happens to be again a function.

This [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) technique is really crucial for good Haskell code; partial application makes many things very concise without sacrificing readability. For example,

```
GHCi> map (logBase 2) [1,2,4,8,16]
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Here I've used `logBase` as a function of a single argument (`2`), which gives me a simple number→number function that can be mapped over a list. Without currying, I would have needed to write `map (\x -> logBase(2,x)) [1,2,4,8,16]`.

Answer (score 6):

Giving a function of two arguments only one is resulting in a [partial application](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_application) of that function, whose result is a function of one (the remaining) argument. While in your case the signature of the returned function is `Integer -> Integer`.